# How to insert Excel table in openoffice doc table?

Tags: insert, openoffice-writer

I have table in oneoffice (5*6). How can i insert data from excel sheet?

Regards

Comment: from java or from openoffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, import excel sheet into openoffice, select part that you need, copy it, then paste to the desired document.

Comment: How to import sheet in openoffice?

Comment: Ok, I opened spreadsheet with interoffice and went to file menu and opened document. But when i made an attempt to copy & paste, table does not fit in the existing table in word. Is there any way to do it by paste special.

Comment: I cannot edit my question and provide pictures as i have <10 reputation. Can i open a new question with picture if any moderator has no pblm.

Comment: you can use free picture hosting and post picture here.

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/tay2nz5cl/a824699f/  http://postimage.org/image/tay2nz5cl/a824699f/

Comment: what do you don't like? If table is too small, you can hopefully drag it by its edges.

Comment: Not only small but its background color and border color is different. So i need to put in excel table in existing table (libreoffice).

Comment: OOO has many bugs during excel import. I can suggest you to change color/resize it manually. Also may be you should file bug report on ooo web site...

Comment: I m not sure there is bug or not. I just want to copy excel sheet into libreoffice existing table. I just tried to copy but size it bigger and i resized it but that look stretched.